# Getting html of <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the following function to try and get the html of a  element by referencing it from the row above (I feel I have to do this for a certain reason that I won't go into).

```
function test() {
    var rowAmount = $("#orderTable > tbody > tr").length;    
    for(i = 0; i < rowAmount; i++) {
        $( "#orderTable > tbody > tr :eq(i)" ).setAttribute( "id", "row" + (i + 1) );    
    }
   alert($( "tr#row1" ).next().find( "td.qty" ).html());
}
```

I am using the for loop to set the id of the rows I have, the ones I wish to reference from.  I will be inserting new rows depending on the value within these.

The error I am getting is this line,

```
$( "#orderTable > tbody > tr :eq(i)" ).setAttribute( "id", "row" + (i + 1) );
```

is returning an error, undefined is not a function.

Does anyone know why?

Thanks in advance.  Mike.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) is a javascript function NOT jquery(you try to use it with a jquery object). You can use jquery [.attr()](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) like:

```
$("#orderTable > tbody > tr :eq(" + i + ")").attr("id", "row" + (i + 1));
```

Here is an example:

```js
var i = 1;
$("#orderTable > tbody > tr :eq(" + i + ")").attr("id", "row" + (i + 1));
```

```css
#row2 {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="orderTable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Something so simple!!  It works perfectly now!  Mike

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#orderTable > tbody > tr :eq(" + i + ")" )
```

Your i is inside the quotes and therefor i will be treated as an character not as an numeric index.

Comment: Check your selector, if it selects anything and set the attr like this:

$( "#orderTable > tbody > tr :eq(" + i + ")" ).attr("id", ("row" + (i++)));

Answer (score 0):

Your index (i) is encapsulated in quotes, therefore the code is not looking for the index of the current loop. Format your code like this ↓.

```
$("#orderTable > tbody > tr :eq(" + i + ")")
```

Otherwise your code is fine.